# Error when mounting a read-only persistent disk on Google compute engine

Tags: linux, centos, google-compute-engine

I'm having an issue when mounting a read-only persistent disk to a running instance in Google Compute engine.
The error is:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
safe_format_and_mount:        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
safe_format_and_mount:        In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
safe_format_and_mount:        dmesg | tail  or so
```

If I unattached the disk, and re-attach it as read-write, it mounts perfectly fine. 
So it seems specific to read only disks and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about mounting read-only disks.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add what your mount command or fstab contains?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal
It's a general error when mounting a read-only disk.

The mount command is

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/[disk_partition] [mounting dir]
```

Let me emphasise that you have to mount the partition not the drive itself.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following article to mount your disk to running instance in read_only mode.
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attach_disk

Useful commands:

gcutil attachdisk --disk=,mode=read_only

sudo mount /dev/disk/by-id/google- /

Comment: Hi Faiz, thanks for the response.  I've actually done exactly that, but continue to get that same error. Attaching the disk isn't an issue, I see it in the /dev/disk area, but when I mount it, I get the error above.